# how to iterate list of numbers store in numbers using loop in linux?

Tags: linux, loops

I have a numbers 10, 60, 30, 40, 20 which is stored in one variable

how to print these numbers using loop (while or for)?

```
echo "$num1"
10
60
30
40
20

for i in {"$num1"}
do
   echo $i
done
```

My output : `{}`

but I want the output

```
10
60
30
40
20
```

Comment: Don't put the variable in quotes or `{}`

Comment: The main point of quoting is to prevent the variable from being split into words. Why are you doing it if you want it to be split?

Comment: can you edit the for loop code?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the quotes and curly braces. The quotes prevent splitting the variable into words, and the curly braces have no meaning at all in this context.

```
for i in $num1
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

However, in general it's usually better to use an array rather than a string with space-separated items. The above code won't work properly if any of the items have wildcard characters, because removing the quotes allows filename expansion to be done.

But if the items are just numbers, it will be OK.